# Move circle to random place

Tags: java, applet

i am making this java applet, which draws a circle, i need to move circle to a random place when i hover to it with mouse coursor, right now my applet draws circle in a random place and changes the color when i hover circle with mouse, but how to make it also to move to a random place? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class circle extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener 
{ 
 // The X-coordinate and Y-coordinate of the last Mouse Position. 
     int xpos; 
     int ypos;
//generate random place for circle (in coordinates from 0 to 400
     int x=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
     int y=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
     int width;
     int height;

 // wll be true when the Mouse is in the circle 
     boolean active;

     public void init()  
     {
         width=40;
         height=40;
  // Add the MouseMotionListener to applet 
      addMouseMotionListener(this); 
     }
     public void paint(Graphics g)  
     { 
          if (active){g.setColor(Color.black);} 
          else {g.setColor(Color.blue);}
          g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 200, 200);

  // This will show the coordinates of the mouse 
  // at the place of the mouse. 
          g.drawString("("+xpos+","+ypos+")",xpos,ypos);

     }

 // This will be excuted whenever the mousemoves in the applet 
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)  
     {  
          xpos = me.getX(); 
          ypos = me.getY(); 
  // Check if the mouse is in the circle 
         if (xpos > x&& xpos < x+width && ypos > y  
        && ypos < y+height)  
               active = true; 
          else  
              active = false; 
  //show the results of the motion 
          repaint();

     }

     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)  
     { 
     }

  }
```

Comment: Simple: Create a Random field and use its `nextInt(some_upper_value)` method when setting your xpos and ypos.

Comment: what should trigger the moving to a random location?

Comment: the mouse pointer, when it moves in circle (or very close to it, doesn't metter). As far as I understand that i should write these actions in public void paint function, in if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put copy of

```
    x=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
    y=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
```

into condition in your **paint()** method

```
    public void paint(Graphics g)  
     { 
      if (active){ 
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          //here
          x=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
          y=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
      }
      ...
```

to "refresh" the position when mouse is over

---

**EDIT**

As @MadProgrammer writing below in a comment **paint()** method is not the best place to place a logic of application. The better place to change the position is the listener where you are setting **active** flag to *True*.

Instead of pasting the x,y... lines into pain() method you should rather paste it here:

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)  
    {
       ...
       if (xpos > x&& xpos < x+width && ypos > y && ypos < y+height)  
       {
           active = true;
           //here
           x=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
           y=(int)(Math.random() * 401);
       } 
       else  
           ...
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of paint is to paint the current state of the component, it shouldn't contain any logic, because paint can be called for any number of reasons, which might generate unexpected results

Comment: Good point - then it should be moved to the part when **active** flag is being set (in a listener method)

Comment: The logic for generating the location should be in be, based on the OP's code, in the `MouseListener` (if that's what you're saying)